# Shell: don't fail git clone if folder already exists

Tags: git, shell

I'm writing an automated script.

At some point, I'm calling `git clone <repo>`. But there is a chance this operation is already done.

How can I call `git clone --no-fail` so that it ignores if repository exists?

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The most stable solution would be to simply let it fail and print the error message. If you think that's too ugly for your scenario, you may redirect it to /dev/null:

```
folder="foo"
if ! git clone "${url}" "${folder}" 2>/dev/null && [ -d "${folder}" ] ; then
    echo "Clone failed because the folder ${folder} exists"
fi
```

---

Otherwise you can do something like this:

```
if [ ! -d "$FOLDER" ] ; then
    git clone "$URL" "$FOLDER"
fi
```

but that would be vulnerable to race conditions.

Comment: I'm not too worried about race conditions. But I'd have found it interesting if there was a check on if the directory is the actual git one (by looking at git remote or something). A `mkdir -p`-like behavior. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger Yeah, I was also searching the man page, but it looks like there isn't..

Answer (score 30):

It makes the repo latest.

```
git -C "$TARGET_DIR" pull || git clone https://github.com/<repo>.git "$TARGET_DIR"
```

Comment: This looks good, we are cloning an external tool repo for CI. We'll try it

Comment: works perfectly! If you need to specify the branch do `git -C "$DIR" pull origin v0.1`

Answer (score 21):

A bit late to the party but I'm doing something similar but I want to ensure the repo is up to date if it already exists so to expand on the above answer if the repo already existed you could then pull to ensure it's up to date.

```
if [ ! -d "$FOLDER" ] ; then
    git clone $URL $FOLDER
else
    cd "$FOLDER"
    git pull $URL
fi
```

Answer (score 9):

`git clone $url || true` would make shell runing with `set -e` not fail on `git clone` having had failed.

If this is not what you want then the suggested solutions with explicit testing for the target directory being already there should work.

The only problem with them is that you'd need to simulate Git's approach to figuring out its name.

Something like this should work:

```
url=git://host/path/name.git
last=${url##*/}
bare=${last%%.git}
test -e "$bare" || git clone "$url"
```

Those "tricks" with `##` and `%%` are [standard featues of the "parameter expansion" rules of POSIX shells](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02).

Answer (score 8):

There are no options in `git clone` to avoid cloning if clone already exist. Your best bet is:

```
[ ! -d 'MyRepo' ] && git clone https://github.com/Myorg/MyRepo.git
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell us why it could already be there, or any context.

I would very like add a `[ -e $folder ] && rm -rf $folder` (making sure `$folder` is sane) before the `git clone` because I would not want my software to use any old folder which just happens to lie around there in who knows which state...

Comment: The `rm -rf` approach is interesting. But ideally, the clone operation wouldn't be repeated if folder exists and is the same.

Comment: Well, you can't know if the folder is the same. What if the folder is there but contains a very old version of the repository? Or is on the wrong branch?

Answer (score -1):

With Git 2.30.1 (Q1 2021), the documentation is clear regarding the risk of race condition for multiple concurrent `git clone`:

See [commit a4a1ca2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a4a1ca22ef913adf3de9e72e525a2cd436742009) (11 Jan 2021) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8782bfb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8782bfbf01a367e77079c4d835328ca4c5da1561), 15 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`Documentation/git-clone.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a4a1ca22ef913adf3de9e72e525a2cd436742009): document race with --local
>
> <sup>Suggested-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> When running '[`git clone --local`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a4a1ca22ef913adf3de9e72e525a2cd436742009/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L46)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---local))</sup>, the operation may fail if another process is modifying the source repository.
> Document that this race condition is known to hopefully help anyone who may run into it.

`git clone` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a4a1ca22ef913adf3de9e72e525a2cd436742009/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L60-L63):

> *NOTE*: this operation can race with concurrent modification to the
> source repository, similar to running `cp -r src dst` while modifying
> `src`.

Comment: Isn't this a separate problem (concurrent modification of **source** repo) from the one in the question (**target** repo might already exist)?

Comment: @das-g True, I put there as another illustration of a possible race condition involving `git clone`.